Energy band structure
I am trying to recreate a plot depicting the energy band structure of a semiconductor, and the overall outcome is great. However, I encountered a couple of issues:

I'm unable to reproduce the horizontal line above the label "Conduction band."

The three dots representing electrons should be separate from this horizontal line, similar to how the holes are depicted in the valence band.


These are the code lines I used:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Drawing the valence band
    \fill[cyan!20] (-2,0) rectangle (2,0.5);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, below, yshift=-2mm] {Valence band};
    
    % Drawing the conduction band
    \draw[thick] (-2,2) -- (2,2) node[midway, above, yshift=2mm] {Conduction band};

    % Drawing the energy gap label
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0) -- (2.2,2) node[midway, right] {$E_g \sim 1 \text{ eV}$};
    
    % Drawing electrons in the conduction band
    \filldraw[black] (-1.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (-0.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (0.5,2) circle (2pt);
    \filldraw[black] (1.5,2) circle (2pt);
    
    % Drawing holes in the valence band
    \filldraw[white, thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (-1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (-0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (0.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
    \filldraw[white, thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw[thick] (1.5,0.25) circle (2pt);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

Thank you in advance. 

Welcome. // I think the graphic is a bit misleading, as the energy gap is a gap. So it’s ok to have electrons in the CB (at its edge), while the blue region with holes can’t be inside the gap.

I took a liberty and markup your code in your code fragment that is now shown more clear. Please, always provide complete small document (MWE; Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem (similarly to what you can see in answer below). Also it will be of big help, if you add a sketch of desired result.

Something like this:

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}     
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1,
            > = Straight Barb,
   dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=1.6pt}, 
     N/.style = {fill=#1!30, minimum height=4mm, minimum width=50mm, 
                 anchor=west}
                        ]
% Drawing the conduction band
\node (n1)  [N=gray, label=Conduction band] at (-1,2) {};
\node (n2)  [N=cyan, label=Valence band]    at (-1,0) {};

% Drawing electrons
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
{
    \node [dot=black] at  (\x,2) {};
    \node [dot=white] at  (\x,0) {};
}

% Drawing the energy gap label
\draw[<->] (n1.south east) to ["$E_g \sim\qty{1}{eV}$"] (n2.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Nice, but from a physics point of view see my comment above https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722077/energy-band-structure#comment1796487_722077.

@MS-SPO, well, i haven't any intention to solve physical problems ,I  limited myself only to TikZ and to OP problem (if I correctly understood it).
